# OpenGL ES 2.0 Type casting

Tags: casting, type-conversion, opengl-es-2.0

Is type casting from float to GLfloat safe? I don't care how much precision is lost or gained if it represents the same geometric shape correct enough. I don't wanna port/rewrite all the general library to make it GL compatible. If there is no issue, I am gonna use GL only in critical functions. For example, when writing draw() funciton. That is, casting will be automatic after passing the float parameters to a cube function for example. Can I do that? Is the casting safe enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely safe and with no loss of precision, since `float` and `GLfloat` are exactly the same.

`GLfloat` merely exists for compatibility between platforms where floats may be defined differently.

In general, though, its declaration is:

```
typedef float GLfloat;
```